# GTK/GDK/x11 Remove the Close/Max/Min Buttons

Tags: gtk, x11, gdk

Is it possible to use GTK/GDK/X11 to write a function which on call, hides the min/max/close buttons, and on call again I can show them again?

I found way to disable them but not remove them. Any help would be awesome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use [`gtk_window_set_titlebar()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-titlebar) to create a custom titlebar to replace the default titlebar. Create your own minimize, maximize, and close buttons for the titlebar. Then you can hide and show them as needed.

You can't do that with the default titlebar, as it is not under GTK's control, nor that of X; it's controlled by the window manager.

Comment: Thanks very much @Ptomato so this is very WM dependent huh?